# could not open git/commit_editmsg

Tags: git, commit

I have a git repository linked to a dropbox folder.
Recently, I have switched my laptop to another, and now i can not perform the function "git commit -am". I keep getting this error message:
"could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Permission denied.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Liron

Comment: Yes. it is still give this error after writing only git commit -a

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you're on a Windows machine, the chances are that you modified a hidden file and no longer have write permissions to the hidden file.

To solve this, simply navigate to your .git folder and delete the "COMMIT_EDITMSG" file.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me with Windows 10 & GIT via PhpStorm

Answer (score 5):

This is an file permission issue, user you are currently logged on does not have permissions to use the files.

If that's your repo, you may try:

- switching to other user who owns the repo
- changing the owner of the repo (`sudo chown youruser -R yourrepodir/`)
- changing the permissions for the particular files using `chmod` (you should avoid using `0777` as it is not secure)

Comment: You can stash it before you commit and save the stash changes. Then commit your data.

Answer (score 0):

try this  `git init --shared=0777`

Comment: Specify that the git repository is to be shared amongst several users. This allows users belonging to the same group to push into that repository.

Comment: shouldnt it be ennough to change the access right of the folder? Like `chmod 755 <folder>` for information about chmod http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I had a git repo inside a git repo in a working copy.. hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the git app you use (whether GUI, cmd or bash) is running as an Administrator. This of course apply if you are using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, here the steps , how I solved the issue.

1) first checked the file permission( and found, only root having access )

`$ls -l .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13 Jun 11 07:54 .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`

2) logged in as root and changed file permission

`# chown arun:arun .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` ( here `arun` is my username, refer `chown` command for more details )

3) Now file permission changed and able to commit without any issues !

`$ls -l .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`

`-rw-r--r-- 1 arun arun 12 Jun 16 11:47 .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG

And then re-run the commit.

```
rm -rf .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```