# Can't commit on Git - although I'm an acknowledged user

Tags: git

Running git on OVM Ubuntu, when checking for valid credential all is OK:

```
git config user.name 
roland
```

but when I attempt to commit

```
 git commit –m “add an ‘about’ page
```

I get the error message:

```
 fatal: could not open ‘.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG’: Permission denied
```

when I run git log  I see that previous commits have been ascribed to

```
 Author: root<root@mymodem.box>
```

Any clues as to what to do to enable authorship of commits, etc.? 
This issue arises in a completely local environment.     Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal: could not open '.git/COMMIT\_EDITMSG': Permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917094/fatal-could-not-open-git-commit-editmsg-permission-denied)

Comment: Also related: [could not open git/commit_editmsg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139239/could-not-open-git-commit-editmsg)

Comment: check your umask and the umask of others that have commited to the repository. Be sure it is set so that it doesn't just restrict new folders from being modified by your account.

Answer (score 5):

Try deleting `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`

And then re-run the commit.

Comment: Jay266, I deleted .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG and attempted git commit.  Response was: Errror: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects

Comment: Try this @RCrim http://stackoverflow.com/a/7849784/5117502 and then try deleting .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG again

Comment: rm -rf .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG

Answer (score 3):

You made the previous commits as `root`. Maybe you even initialized the repository as `root`. This means some of the files that git created are owned by `root`. Files owned by `root` can usually not be modified by other users.

The fix is to `chown` all the files in the repo to your normal user ID. This has to be done as `root`.

In general, you should only use `root` credentials for things that *need* them.

Comment: chown of all the files to my normal user id worked. Thanks !